# What is a good way to dry out extra fat after extensive muscle training program?

Tags: weight-loss, muscle, body-fat, burn-fat

I have not accumulated muscles (5-6 times training per week) two months without burning fat because I do not want to lose muscles.

Nutrition

- Some say I should eat little BCAA before sleeping.

Weekly program

- Assume no running in weekly program for half marathon.
- Assume only 1.5 hour weekly cardio which is divided steadily to the weekly program.

Gym program

- 4 x 1.5 hour muscular training

  - #1 day: biceps, delts, pectoralis major, rectus abdominis
  - #2-3 days: latissimus dorsi, back, rectus, rectus abdominis
  - rest day
  - 4(5)th day: triceps, rectus abdominis, trapezoideus
  - rest day

by which I have tried to minimise the overtraining of muscles of one organ.

- not training biceps and triceps at the same day.
- not training trapezoideus and latissimus dorsi at the same time

Gym exercises

- Pushups 30 x 3 for biceps brachii, triceps brachii, delts, stomach, ... with different hand levels relative to the shoulders and with changing rhythm of one leg etc
- Flanks - 60s - 30 s - rectus abdominis
- Pullups (50kg - 40kg - 30 kg) x 3 for triceps, latissimus dorsi
- Rectus abdominis - on the bench (40 angle), foot up 15 x 3 left, middle, right
- Triceps machine - 55 kg - 45 kg - 35 kg - 15x3
- Dents machine - 10 kg x 3, 5 kg x 2
- Weights sideways with one hand, supporting spine with another hand to keep spine straight - 10-20kg x 5 for biceps brachii and triceps

which are divided according to muscles for different days

**What is a good way to burn fat after extensive muscle training?**

Comment: So you're training 6 times a week and run half marathons (I assume you train for those too). If you're not very advanced training-wise or a genetic freak you're setting yourself up for overtraining. It might very well be that you're already doing too much, which hinders your progress fat-loss wise. Anyway, to give a meaningful answer, we'd need more information. What is your training-plan (what split, what intensity, what exercises), how much cardio do you do, how much do you eat? As it stands, one could only give you general advice, which won't help much, I'm afraid.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I tried to add details of my weekly program. There are some small muscles missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're indeed doing the above exercises consistently *(hopefully you take time to rest)*, you should not need any other exercise to burn fat. Those will torch your fat for you. What you might want to do is consistently track your body fat percentage. 
 
There are tools on the market for measuring your body fat percentage. Get one and measure your fat percentage. Get a tape to measure your waistline too consistently. If there isn't a consistent decline in your fat percentage every 2 weeks *(along with a decline in your waistline)*, you need to revamp your routine. 
 
 
Happy exercising.